# show more in a div with php and css

Tags: php, css, taxonomy

I am trying to implement show more links in several divs (like here http://www.gutscheinpony.de/outletcity.html, you click on details and you get the hidden div)
However I am getting via php and taxonomy up to 50 fields like on these side and i need individual ids so that i can open each div seperatly. Problem is that I need to give each div a variable id via php!!! but i am stuck. You can see the problem here http://cloud0815.joloshop.com/shops/1822direkt (click on both "Show More" text) and only the first will open!!!)

Comment: Plenty of ways to do this out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717181/cut-text-after-x-amount-of-characters and look through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truncate+string+php

Comment: thanks but, thats not the problem. I would like to cut the text after one line and have a (link) more... and the other lines should slide open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you do not need to give each div an individual id.  You can give each "Show more" link a class like 'show-more'.  Then, bind the links to a click handler.  The $(this) variable tells you which of the 50 links was clicked on.  How you select the div containing the hidden text depends on your markup, but here's an example of what you can do:

PHP:

```
 /* Inside a loop */
 <?php 
       $full_text = get_the_content();
       $period_pos = strpos($full_text, ".");
       $excerpt = substr($full_text, 0, $period_pos+1);    // Get the first line, assuming that a line ends with a period.
       $rest = substr($full_text, $period_pos+1);          // Get the rest of the text
 ?>
 <div class="excerpt">
      <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="rest">
      <?php echo $rest; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="show-more-div">
     <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".show-more").click(function(){
           $(this).parent().prev().slideDown();     
      });
 });
```

Comment: Can i also instead of 20 characters chose first line of the content?

Comment: Thanks, last one. I am getting the content to show via php, where do I put the code <?php the_content(); ?>

Comment: You can set the $full_text variable to get_the_content();  See my edit.

Comment: tried it, unfortunately nothing happens, all content is shown right a way and if i click on show more the side srcolls to the top, or am i missing something?

Comment: I tried everything, not working, just shows everything and show more is not functioning, need really some help with this..

Comment: You'll also need to initialize the "rest" div in the css so that it is hidden when the page loads.  So, in css, do: .rest{ display: none; }